# Disabling a slice for a Highcharts pie chart when creating the chart

Tags: highcharts

I have some pie charts on my site and they show quite a bit of data. I was wondering if there is a way to load the data, but initially hide any data that is less than some arbitrary value. When I say hide, I mean in the same way you can hide the certain data by clicking on the label in the legend. Then through the legend, have the user be able to show this data on the graph by clicking on the label in the legend. Is there a property or something I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: You can, but you would need to use the highcharts api : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart

Comment: That's what I'm using. I was more looking for some direction as to which property or function I could use that would get the chart to behavior like I described. Any insight here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define any variable as maxValue, then iterate on each point and call setVisible as false.

```
    var minValue = 10

    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point){
        if(point.y < minValue) {
            point.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ct2jejgv/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `this.chart.series[i].hide()` / `.show()`. In your script, manually search for series less than your value and hide them like above. Its a simple foreach.